# Does decimate help viewport performance?

Tags: modifiers, performance

I'm seeking to increase viewport performance to help when posing/animating. Does it work to just toss a decimate on my objects? Will this actually help performance, or just add the extra calculation of the decimate onto my stack? (I would put it before the armature, of course.)

Comment: It should imrpove performance a bit, but if it really decimates a lot of geometry. If there're 1,5 mln faces and decimating to 0.3 mln then it worked better but I tested Object mode, Pose mode might behave differently. If there's not so much geometry to remove then might be just another modifier